# How to add a progress event listener to a prototype Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

How to add a progress event listener to a prototype Ajax request ?

I didn't find anything in the prototype doc about this ..

I found some example using jQuery but not with prototype.

```
new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
 method:'get',
 onSuccess: function(transport) {..},
 onFailure: function() {..}
});
```

using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    // Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            //Do something with upload progress
            console.log(percentComplete);
        }
   }, false);

   // Download progress
   xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
       if (evt.lengthComputable) {
           var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
           // Do something with download progress
           console.log(percentComplete);
       }
   }, false);

   return xhr;
},
type: 'POST',
url: "/",
data: {},
success: function(data){..}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that I use in my code for doing AJAX file uploads

```
new Ajax.Request('backend.php',{'method':'get','onCreate':function(t){
    t.transport.upload.onprogress = function(event){
        if(event.lengthComputable)
        {
            console.log((event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0)+'%');
        }
    }
},'onSuccess':function(result){
    console.log("success")
}});
```

Comment: Thanks! I also added `t.transport.onprogress = function(event){..}`